# How can I autoaccept events from a particular Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-events

There is a group that I am in that holds events that I always want to attend. However, there is a strict limit on how many can RSVP, and it always runs out of spots (if you aren't in the first N people who clicked "Going", you aren't allowed to attend). If I don't check Facebook in awhile, I get excluded. Is there a way to automatically reply "Going" to each event from this group? Some sort of script I could write or setting or something?